# Calculate SHA256 checksum in Dart

Tags: dart

There is a library "crypto" in dart as documented here:
https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/crypto.html

I want to calculate the SHA256 checksum of a given string on the client,
the could would be something like this:

```
    var sha256 = new SHA256();
    sha256.add('message'.codeUnits);
    var digest = sha256.close();
    var hexString = CryptoUtils.bytesToHex(digest);
    assert(hexString ==
      'ab530a13e45914982b79f9b7e3fba994cfd1f3fb22f71cea1afbf02b460c6d1d');
```

However I was unable to even import that library to use the SHA256 object...
None of these works:

```
    import 'dart:crypto';
    import 'crypto';
```

I could not find the SHA256 in my Dart directory (I am using Dart 1.0.0 STABLE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Add crypto dependency to pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  crypto: any
```

2) Add the correct import statement to your .dart program:

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
```

3) Run pub get (In the Dart Editor: Tools -> Pub Get)

--

You'll find such a information in the pub repository for the crypto package:

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/crypto

Answer (score 18):

The answers from 2013 are outdated again, as the [crypto package's](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/crypto) API has been updated and simplified:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

main() {
    List<int> bytes = utf8.encode('message');
    String hash = sha256.convert(bytes).toString();
    assert(hash == 'ab530a13e45914982b79f9b7e3fba994cfd1f3fb22f71cea1afbf02b460c6d1d');  // true
    print(hash);
}
```

Comment: in 2024 the answer is even simpler: `var bytes = utf8.encode(item); var digest = sha1.convert(bytes);`

Answer (score 8):

The [crypto package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/crypto) has to be import with :

```dart
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
```

Moreover the code snippet you paste is outdated. You should do :

```dart
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

main() {
  var sha256 = new SHA256();
  sha256.add('message'.codeUnits);
  var digest = sha256.close();
  var hexString = CryptoUtils.bytesToHex(digest);
  print(hexString ==
      'ab530a13e45914982b79f9b7e3fba994cfd1f3fb22f71cea1afbf02b460c6d1d'); //true
}
```